# Argument of type 'React.ReactInstance' is not assignable to parameter of type 'React.ReactInstance'

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have got the following error in a react component, developing with **TypeScript**:

```
Argument of type 'React.ReactInstance' is not assignable to parameter of type 'React.ReactInstance'.
  Type 'Component<any, {}>' is not assignable to type 'ReactInstance'.
    Type 'React.Component<any, {}>' is not assignable to type 'React.Component<any, {}>'. Two different types with this name exist, but they are unrelated.
```

Here's the code (hopefully the relevant bits):

```
import * as React from "react";
import * as ReactDOM from "react-dom";

interface IToolbarProps {
  editorNode: React.ReactInstance;
}

export default class Toolbar extends React.Component<IToolbarProps, IToolbarState> {
  componentDidUpdate() {
    const parent = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.props.editorNode);
  }
}
```

The `findDOMNode` is the part complaining. The error message looks suspiciously like some weird conflict, but I haven't got good ideas right now. Anyone knows what is happening?

Comment: I got this when @types/react was at v16, but @types/react-dom was at v15